# Find xml tag and skip if it does not exists with python 2.7 and ElementTree

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I have an XML file that looks like the one below. I want to find a specific tag that may or may not exist. Now when I try

`tree.find('./Altitude).text = '1000ft'`

To change the altitude value and my tag does not exist
I get an error

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

If it does not exist, but what I want is for my program to skip the tag if it does not exists instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Basically what I am trying to do is the following. 
1.Search the xml file for certain tag
2.If there are attributes find the attribute we need to change and change its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped using the find() method. Instead I iterate through the whole tree and check for the tag I want to find then check it against the dictionary I created.

```
for child in root.iter():
     for key, val customDict.items():
         if child.tag == key:
               do something
```

This may not be the best way to do this but it works.